# In the dataflow programming paradigm programs are modeled as directed graphs. Are the edges of the graph variables? And are the vertexes functions?

Tags: graphs, programming-languages

As I understand it in dataflow programming, programs are structured as directed graphs, an example of which is below
[image]

Is it true to say that the arrows (or edges) represent the variables within a program and the vertexes (blue circles) represent programmatic functions? Or is this too much of a simplification?

I am interested in understanding how dataflow languages actually apply graph theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be precise, the nodes represent the ***blocks*** (consisting a set of statements) and the edges represent ***possible data flow*** (the execution path).

Now basically the data flow analysis gives the information regarding the definition and use of data in the program  (***Available Expression, Reaching Definition, Live variable***).  This information is needed for code optimization.

And moving on to the graph theory applications in the compiler design, I would say ***Register allocation*** is the best example (Btw this can be done after gathering information from the data flow analysis).

This is a vast area, not easy to explain everything clearly. So, I would highly recommend to read a good book on compilers to get deeper insights